# Working with $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, server-side

Is there any risk of a session expiring before the other session even if they're declared at the same time?

I want to declare 40+ variables as sessions, but only if they didn't already exist, like so:

```
if (!array_key_exists('user', $_SESSION))
{
$_SESSION['user']['username'] = "";
$_SESSION['user']['age'] = "";
$_SESSION['user']['location'] = "";
//...and 40+ more
}
```

But if one of those sessions expired before the others, it would ruin the whole code. Is that a possibility?

Thank you!

Comment: The session is the container that the variables are in. They will all expire at the same time when the session goes away.

Comment: Ceci n'est pas un session...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_SESSION is an associative array. So the things you store in it are not separate "sessions", but values in the array. Since $_SESSION is thrown away when the session expires, all its values are gone at the same time.

So no: one such value in the $_SESSION array does not expire before another, they expire at the same time. For more info on using sessions and $_SESSION: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

Check in php.ini the value set for session.gc_maxlifetime is the ID lifetime in seconds.

Default is 24 mins I think.

Also check this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php
Is there a limit of variables? No there is not!